# Article appendix with sections and toc entries in the form "Appendix A"

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, cross-referencing, appendices, article

I have been trying to get the appendix for my thesis done.
I've read a lot about it and as always you can chose between a fiddly way and a magic package that doas the job to solve a problem (I usually prefer a magic package). Unfortunately both approaches didn't work out, so here is how far I got.

## Four requirements

This is what my appendix should look like for a document with class 'article',
there are **four requirements**:

Sections should look like this:

```
Appendix A    Title1

Appendix B    Title2
```

They should appear in the same way in the TOC:

```
Appendix A    Title1                    56

Appendix B    Title2                    88
```

`\ref{app:foo}` should be able to return the letter of the corresponding appendix.

Tables and Figures should be labeled as *Table A1.* or *Figure A1.*

## Fiddly approach

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
  \renewcommand\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section}}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{section}\arabic{figure}}
  \renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{section}\arabic{table}}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Dolor sit amet}
Have a look at \ref{app:foobar}

\appendix
\section{foo} \label{app:foobar}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{foo}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\textbf{ a } & \textbf{ b }\\
1 & 3 \\
2 & 4\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It worked out pretty good. The problem is that in the TOC the appendix title "foo" gets written onto "Appendix A". Is there a way to adjust the position of the title in the TOC?

## Magic package 'appendix'

The solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690679/add-appendix-before-a-in-thesis-toc) unfortunately applies only to the documentclass 'report' where chapters are used. But my document has the class 'article' and no chapters whatsoever. I also don't like it that the appendix titles are not in the same lines as "Appendix A" and in table labels there is a dot between the section and table number "Table A.1.".

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Dolor sit amet}
Have a look at \ref{app:foobar}

\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{Consectetur adipiscing elit} \label{app:foobar}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \caption{foo}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \textbf{ a } & \textbf{ b }\\
    1 & 3 \\
    2 & 4\\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
  \chapter{Mauris euismod}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Is there a proper way using the *appendix* package? I played around with the *toc*, *title* and *titletoc* arguments for the package. But it didn't do what it said in the manual.

It would great if someone could help me, no matter on which approach!

## Update

Thank you very much for your help! The first comment from Alan Munn reassuring me that the appendix package should work as expected helped me to find the error. This is the erroneous code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%appendix
\usepackage[title,titletoc,toc]{appendix}

%format paragraphs
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}{\theparagraph}{}{}[.] %format paragraph italic and ser a period after it
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{0pt}{*1} %remove spacing and add one characterspace after paragraph

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Method}
(The entire results are detailed in Appendix \ref{app:bar}).   

\begin{appendices}
\section{foo} \label{app:foo}
asd
\section{bar} \label{app:bar}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

The three lines which format paragraphs cause the appendices to fail in the toc. If taken out, everything works fine. But what about my paragraphs then? Do I have to pose another question for that? ;)

Comment: The `appendix` package works with the `article` class too. (It checks to see whether the document has chapters or not and does the right stuff accordingly.) Can you show the code you used with `article` class that didn't work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added an update to my question with the erroneous code.

Comment: Apparently package _titlesec_ is conflicting with package _appendix_. If I add `\usepackage{titlesec}` the appendices in the toc are displayed wrong.

Comment: Yes, `titlesec` and `appendix` conflict. However, the modification for `\paragraph` is easy to achieve without `titlesec`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `appendix` package (adding the `title` package option) and a redefinition of `\thetable` and `\thefigure`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Dolor sit amet}
Have a look at \ref{app:foobar}

\begin{appendices}
  \renewcommand\thetable{\thesection\arabic{table}}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection\arabic{figure}}
  \section{Consectetur adipiscing elit} \label{app:foobar}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \caption{foo}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \textbf{ a } & \textbf{ b }\\
    1 & 3 \\
    2 & 4\\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
  \section{Mauris euismod}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To change the `\paragraph` formatting. add these lines to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this is the perfect solution for my requirements!

Comment: I searched all over this stackexchange for the simplest answer to this question and yours finally cleared something up for me! `\appendix` IS NOT the same thing as `\begin{appendices}`. The latter works with the appendix package, the former does not.